# Subset minimizing the cost of a one-sided matching, involving preference orders

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, assignment-problem

We're given a set of items $A=\{1,\dots,m\}$ and a set of people $B=\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Each person has a preference ordering for the items in $A$.  Each item in $A$ has a specific positive cost for each specific person in $B$: item $i$'s cost to person $j$ is $c_{ij}$.

For any non-empty subset $T \subseteq A$ of items, we can imagine each person in $B$ choosing exactly one item in $T$: their top preference out of all the items in $T$ according to their preference ordering.  (Different people can choose the same item.)  Let $c(T)$ be the total cost of the items selected in this way.

Given the costs $c_{ij}$, I'd like to find a non-empty subset $T \subseteq A$ that makes $c(T)$ as small as possible.  What is the complexity of this task?

It looks like a NP-Complete problem to me.  It seems quite similar to a subset-sum or travel salesman problem, but I'm not sure. Do you have any suggestion for a reduction or a polynomial-time algorithm?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have made my question more formal. I don't think it is related to network flow problem since according to the hint the only possible solution is using DP. I have already made largest effort to think of the question and try to relate it with vertex cover,tsp,subset sum, but reduction problem is sometimes too tricky for a newbee, it is not just the issue of effort. Also, i even don't have a clear direction whether  this is NP-Complete or not. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarifications. I've edited the question to try to make this clearer.  In what context did you run across this problem?  Can you share anything about the motivation or application?

Comment: This is a homework problem, I don't know why the professor make it so complicated...Since it is similar to different NP-Complete questions, is it possible to reduce from different NP-Complete problems for different parts and combine them together?